# Why does Jar file execution stops?

Tags: java, executable-jar

I have developed an application that reads and writes register values from a device (meter).

I have created a .jar file of this application and ran it in the command prompt.
I have used the following command for execution:

```
java -jar -Xmx20m -Xms10m ReadWriteDev.jar
```

But after 2-3 hours it terminates. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Is there any error message? Any abnormal behavior etc? It was considered to keep running for how long?

Comment: No i have use try catch also but it wont work while stopping.

Comment: So, you are certain no exception is being caught?

Comment: What is the expected output and how can you say it terminates ? any exception? performing something which it shouldn't perform? or what?

Comment: Yes. It is just stop without any error

Comment: Is there a call to System.exit() anywhere?

Comment: I want to keep it running as windows service work.

Comment: No i havn't written System.exit

Comment: Can i Paste my code?

Comment: Please post some errorlog or at what action when the program is running did the jar exited with the corresponding code.

Comment: Use Java Service Wrapper to run a Java app as a Windows service. http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/introduction.html